# p5.js loadStrings() is doing nothing

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using p5.js for my project, and I have to load some data from a file in another folder.

My js code is written in 'js' folder, and the data file is in 'txt' folder. Both 'js' and 'txt' folders are in the same root directory.

Here's my code,

```
var data;

function preload() {
   data = loadStrings('../txt/data.txt');
   console.log(data);
   console.log(data[0]);
}
```

and here's the logs:

```
0: "abcde"
1: "fghij"
2: "klmno"
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

undefined
```

and here's the request:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/txt/data.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

It shows appropriate result when I print whole array, but when I access each data of array, it goes something wrong. What's wrong in my project?

Comment: Have you tried loading from './txt/data.txt'?

Comment: @pytness Yes. It shows the same result.

Comment: Have you tried checking the network tab in your browser to debug what its happening to that request?

Comment: @pytness I think the request has done successfully, and even when I print entire data array like `console.log(data)`, it shows appropriate result. But when I access each data in array like `console.log(data[0])`, it goes wrong again.

Comment: Could you show us the request and the console logs?

Comment: Request:
`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/txt/data.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`
and console log
`//When console.log(data)
0: "abcde"
1: "fghij"
2: "klmno"
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)   //when console.log(data[0])
undefined`

Comment: Could you update the code example in the post with the comments and the code you are using for each log?

Comment: @pytness I edited the code and added console log and request. Sorry for the poor readability comment

Comment: Hm, strange, try loging `data` multiple times. Also, try logging inside of a setup function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling in the preload, you need to access the data in the setup or draw function.

```
function setup() {

console.log(data[0])
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a callback function to handle the data.

```
function setup() {
 loadStrings('../txt/data.txt', myCallback);
}

function myCallback(data) {
console.log(data[0])
}
```

Comment: That was a problem. Thank you for solving my problem.